# Copy OpenVPN settings

Tags: linux, debian, openvpn

After I install OpenVPN on another device, can I transfer the keys to the server to save me making new keys for all my devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. and you can allso use them at the same time )

Just copy all key listed in client config + config itself to your other devices.

But it is highly dangerous to use this approach for multiple users...

Comment: It's just for me so no worry there. Thank you

Comment: You can only use them at the same time if the server is configured to allow that.